# Powershell script : Set-ADUser -clear with multiple attributes in variable

Tags: active-directory, powershell, command-line-interface

I want to clear multiple attributes by using variable in Powershell script (version 5.1.17763.1007)

It's work :

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear Initials,info
```

It's work also:

```
$emptyParams='Initials'
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

It's not work :

```
$emptyParams='Initials,info'
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

and display :

> Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
>   Parameter name: Initials,info
>   At Set-ADUserDesc.ps1:32 char:9
>   +         Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (S-1-5-21-414636...1575523350-2106:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

Can you explain-me why ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question of why the third method does not work:

**There is no attribute by the name `Initials,Info` which is why the cmdlet fails.  Your input (a string with a comma) is *not* the same as an array of strings.**

The docmentation for the cmdlet [Set-AdUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps) indicates that the -Clear attributes accepts an array of strings (or a single string, which would just be an array with a single element) as valid input:

```
 Set-ADUser
   ...
   [-Clear <String[]>]
   ...
```

Let's go over each scenario you covered in your question.

```
 Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear Initials,info
```

The first method supplies two strings separated by a comma (this is interpreted as an array of strings) to the -Clear parameter.  Good.

```
 $emptyParams='Initials' 
 Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

The second method is supplying a single string (or an array of a single element) to the -Clear parameter. Good.

```
 $emptyParams='Initials,info'
 Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

The final method is actually supplying the attribute "Initials,Info".  As noted above, this is a single string with commas in it, and the cmdlet iterprets it as a single argument.

---

To achieve what I *think* you're going for, you'll need to build and supply an array of valid attribute names.  This should work:

```
$emptyParams = @()
$emptyParams += "Initials"
$emptyParams += "Info"
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

And actually, this should work, too:

```
 $emptyParams='Initials,info'
 Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams.Split(',')
```

Comment: I am confused by the statement "There is no attribute by the name `Initials,Info` which is why the cmdlet fails." If you look at the Docs for `Set-ADUser` it clearly has the `Initials` shown.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps

Answer (score 1):

Instead use -Clear parameter, I use workaround and set value to "$null", like :

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Initials $null
```

Currently, I can't update note field with this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can symply do it by creating a PowerShell array:

```
$emptyParams=@('Initials','info')
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear $emptyParams
```

or 1 line format

```
Set-ADUser -Identity $($user.SID) -Clear @('Initials','info')
```